# Atualizando Dados do XML em Tempo Real com jQuery.get

Tags: jquery, html5, ajax, xml, bootstrap

Estou construindo uma página que possui um carrossel *(com bootstrap 4)* que exibe algumas informações sobre temperaturas. Essas informações vem de um *XML* que será atualizado sempre que ocorrer alguma mudança.

Estou fazendo os testes alterando o arquivo *XML* manualmente, mas não consigo visualizar as alterações. Já tentei o `setTimeout` e o `setInterval` (o `setInterval` repete todo o bloco *HTML*) e não conseguir visualizar as alterações, parece que no caso do `setTimeout`, ele não carrega o *XML* novamente.

Alguém poderia me ajudar a desvendar este mistério? Agradeço desde já pela atenção :)

Código:

```
function temperatures() {
    'use strict';
    $.get('temperature.xml', function (data) {
        $(data).find('temperature').each(function () {
            let $temperature = $(this);
            let type = $temperature.find('type').text();
            let value = $temperature.find('value').text();

            let temperatures = '<div class="carousel-item temperature">';
            temperatures += '<span class="sensor-value">' + value + '</span>';
            temperatures += '<span class="sensor-title">' + type + '</span>';
            temperatures += '</div>';

            $('.temperatures').append($(temperatures));
        });
    });
    setTimeout(temperatures, 1000);
}

$(function () {
    temperatures();
});
```

Comment: `setTimeout` é uma "pausa", ele só executa uma vez. Já o `setInterval`, ele cria um intervalo que se repetirá infinitas vezes. Verifique se não é problema com "cache".

Answer (score -1):

[**setTimeout**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) serve como uma "pausa", ele executa apenas uma vez, no tempo programado. Já o [**setInterval**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval), ele cria um intervalo que se repetirá infinitas vezes (ou até você utilizar o comando `clearInterval()`).

Como você quer apenas os novos resultos (e não repetir os mesmos), é necessário criar um `ID` único para cada valor. Dessa forma você consegue verificar, através do `ID`, se o valor é novo ou repetido.

**Exemplo:**

```
<div class="temperatures"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    function temperatures() {
        'use strict';
        $.get('xml.xml', function (data) {
            $(data).find('temperature').each(function () {
                let $temperature = $(this);
                let type = $temperature.find('type').text();
                let value = $temperature.find('value').text();

                /* Converte para base64 e remove o sinal de igual */
                let id = btoa(value).replace(/=/g, "")

                /**
                 * Verifica se a div com o ID já existe,
                 * caso já exista, ignora. Caso contrário,
                 * adiciona na tela.
                 */
                if (! $("div#"+id).length ) {
                    let html = '<div class="carousel-item temperature" id="' + id + '">';
                    html += '<span class="sensor-value">' + value + '</span>';
                    html += '<span class="sensor-title">' + type + '</span>';
                    html += '</div>';

                    $('.temperatures').append( html );
                }
            });
        }).done( function() {
            setTimeout( temperatures, 1000 )
        } );
    }

    setTimeout(temperatures, 1000)
</script>
```

**Xml de Exemplo:**

```
<temperature>
    <type>Tipo</type>
    <value>Valor</value>
</temperature>
```

Você pode utilizar varias formas de criar um `ID`. Pode ser convertendo para *hexadecimal*, *base64*; utilizando *bitwise*, *md5*, *sha1*; concatenando o *tipo* com o *valor*; adicionar em um `array` e fazer as verificações com a método `Array.find` ou `Array.indexOf` etc.

Comment: Obrigada Valdeir, no caso, o setTimeout chamando a função dentro da mesma repete os comandos no intervalo solicitado, mas infelizmente não funcionou no caso da atualização dos dados do arquivo. Tentarei sua sugestão assim que possível, espero que funcione :)