# Atualizar uma div de um dashboard sem recarregar toda a página html

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Estou finalizando meu TCC e me deparei com um problema. Estou criando um painel de controle administrativo e gostaria q ele exibisse em tempo real um count de uma tabela do meu banco de dados. Me disseram que o ideal para essa situação seria jQuery + Ajax... Alguém teria um exemplo de solução dessa situação para passar por favor?

Obrigado desde já!

Comment: O ideal é *websocket* (afinal, ele foi pensando para isso). *AJAX* não é a melhor opção, mas quebra um galho. Caso esteja disposto apenas com a quebra de galho, você pode utilizar a função `setTimeout` do *JavaScript*. Esta função irá executar um determinado código de tempos em tempos.

Comment: @ValdeirPsr desculpe, mas tenho que discordar absolutamente de sua afirmação, dependendo de como se planeja o sistema e do que tem Ajax vai resolver bem o caso, outra coisa, websocket não foi feito especificamente para isso, o uso dele é amplo. A situação é toda relativa, não tem como afirmar que X é melhor que Y, vai depender de caso a caso, de sistema para sistema, de recursos que a hospedagem fornece e da experiencia com tratar dados, vou te contar sobre um sistema que criei, é um sistema de "pushs" back-end [...]

Comment: [...] basicamente cada usuário tem uma flag baseada em timestamp salva em um arquivo de log proprio então tenho 2 ajax, um que só checa a flag, ou seja não usa banco não retorna dados complexos, retorna só 0 e 1, se retornar um então um ajax para carregar os dados de uma tabela especifica serão recarregados, ou seja o consumo é minimo, as requisições no banco também são minimas e também me aproveito muito de cache HTTP (uso a flag para ignorar o cache se houver mudanças), fora que também uso a resposta HTTP "304 not modified" (que é mais complexo)

Comment: Por ser uma situação simples devo usar o setTimeout?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento O protocolo *websocket* é basicamente uma conexão bidirecional com tempo de resposta muito curto e uma otimização melhor que `XMLHttpRequest` ou `Fetch`. Inclusive um dos motivos para a criação do protocolo foi devido os abusos cometidos com requisições desnecessárias¹. Concordo com a afirmação de que não há uma tecnologia melhor ou pior, além da implementação ser mais complexa. [*Nota ¹*](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455#page-4)

Comment: @ErickLimaFigueiredo Nesses casos sim. (Exemplo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/277307/99718)

Comment: @ValdeirPsr exatamente é bidirecional, então carregar um DIV não é exatamente uma necessidade complexa, não concorda, agora se fosse um sistema de chat ou uma planilha online ou documento de texto com muitas pessoas editando ao mesmo templo, faria sentido do uso de WebSocket para até resolver a "concorrência" de edições e múltiplos acessos que fariam com que coisas como cache não poderiam ser usadas, neste caso não que seja melhor só por ser, mas daria para criar algo mais eficiente e até simples usando websocket.

Comment: Muito obrigado a todos!